# How to send a binary payload with request in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I'm new to JMeter and couldn't figure out yet how to send binary data to the server as the body of a POST request. Please send me some test setup or any suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help if you could be more specific as to what you are trying to do, and things you've already tried that didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

In the `HTTP Request`, did you try to just `Send Files with the Request`?

Comment: See my comment to @rolf's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The jMeter documentation describes how to upload a File as part of your HTTP request. See http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request
(Read the description for the "File Path:" argument)

Comment: Sending a file and sending binary data are not necessarily related. You could have been reading Base64-encoded strings from a CSV file and converting them to byte[] that needs to be passed along with the request.